# Zend framework - how to add CSS and JS only one time in the header without duplication?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

In ZF2, i am trying to load CSS and JS file one time only.

But when i render the page they are loaded twice or three time and causing the site to be extremely slow.

In real page i have bootstrap.css 2 time, style.css 2 time, and JS files also 2 , 3 times.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />

  <?= $this->headTitle(); ?>  
  <?= $this->headMeta(); ?>

  <!-- CSS -->
  <?= $this->headLink()->prependStylesheet('/v2/css/bootstrap.css'); ?>  
  <?= $this->headLink()->prependStylesheet('/v2/css/style.css'); ?>  

  <!-- JS -->
  <?= $this->headScript()->prependFile('/v2/js/jquery-3.1.0.min.js') ?>
  <?= $this->headScript()->prependFile('/v2/js/global.js') ?>

</head>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are echoing the object on each line; remove all `<?=` and replace with just one call to echo.

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />

  <?= $this->headTitle(); ?>  
  <?= $this->headMeta(); ?>

  <!-- CSS -->
  <?php 
    $headLink = $this-headLink();
    $headScript = $this->headScript();

    $headLink->prependStylesheet('/v2/css/bootstrap.css');
    $headLink->prependStylesheet('/v2/css/style.css');

    $headScript->prependFile('/v2/js/jquery-3.1.0.min.js');
    $headScript->prependFile('/v2/js/global.js');

    echo $headLink;
    echo $headScript;
  ?>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to **chain** it, like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />

  <?= $this->headTitle(); ?>  
  <?= $this->headMeta(); ?>

  <!-- CSS -->
  <?= $this->headLink()->prependStylesheet('/v2/css/bootstrap.css')
        ->prependStylesheet('/v2/css/style.css'); ?>  

  <!-- JS -->
  <?= $this->headScript()->prependFile('/v2/js/jquery-3.1.0.min.js')
        ->prependFile('/v2/js/global.js'); ?>
</head>
```

This is the way done for example in [ZendSkeleton layout](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication/blob/master/module/Application/view/layout/layout.phtml).